# Core Plot : Two color axis label

Tags: ios, core-plot, axis-labels

How can we have a two color axis title using Core Plot. 
For example:

```
CPTXYAxis *y = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
y.title = @"Amount [Million $]";
```

I would like to have `Million $` text in a different color than `Amount` text.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `attributedTitle` property instead of the `title`. This takes a `NSAttributedString` that can be formatted any way you want.